# immutability helper - setState

Tags: react-native, immutability

I need to update the state with immutability helper update function but I cannot do it properly. Please help me do it.

Besides you can tell me how to make it without update function. It is all okay.

My initial state object is

```
state = {
  markers: [
    {
      key: 1,
      latlng: {
        latitude: 40.3565,
        longitude: 27.9774
      }
    } 
  ]
```

And my jsonResponse is:

```
[{"latlng":{"latitude":"40.3565","longitude":"27.9774"}},{"latlng":{"latitude":"40.3471","longitude":"27.9598"}},{"latlng":{"latitude":"40","longitude":"27.9708"}}]
```

Now I want to add all data from responseJson to state with ummutable helper update function or without it how can I do it.

Answer (score 1):

First, edit your respone:

```
let response = [{"latlng":{"latitude":"40.3565","longitude":"27.9774"}},{"latlng":{"latitude":"40.3471","longitude":"27.9598"}},{"latlng":{"latitude":"40","longitude":"27.9708"}}]




response = response.reduce((prev,curr,index)=>{
  curr.key = index;
  prev.concat(curr)
},[]);
```

Secondly, create your initial state on your reducer like this:

```
 state = Map({
markers: List()
})
```

Finally, edit your reducer:

```
[FETCH_MARKERS_SUCCESS]: (state, action) => state.merge(action.payload, {loading: false}),
```

Comment: but I, dont know about redux